# How to change the canvas size in HTML?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a game in HTML and JavaScript. I am trying to resize the standard canvas in chrome which is 300 x 150. I want to resize it to 1024 x 576.

Here is my code:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelectory('#canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = 1024
canvas.height = 576
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Add CSS to change the style.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the following line:

```
const canvas = document.querySelectory('#canvas');
```

The 'y' at the end of `querySelector` is a typo and should be removed.

`#` before canvas indicates `id="canvas"` should exist in the HTML, but that is not the case, so the `#` is not necessary and we can select the `canvas` element itself.

I added a black border to the `canvas` and set the background to green. The effect of setting the `height` and `width` is clearly visible.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.style.background = 'green';
canvas.style.border = 'solid 3px black';

canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 576;
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```